# What flow should I use for authentication against Azure AD for a command line based application?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to understand what Azure flow I should use for building a python based command line interface application.  I simply want to be able to have a CLI where I can authenticate the application user without the whole complication of opening web browsers to perform the authentication.  In addition, the desire by my company is to not user username/password authentication.  How do I pick up an authentication token where the user of the application can be identified such that I can use that token within my application to pull other information about the user from the Graph API without the user having to open browsers to enter their credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, it is recommended to use [device code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code) which helps you to easily easily develop command-line tools that run on even Linux or Mac. This flow is also used for applications without a browser.

Please find an  [Python Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-devicecodeflow) for device code flow.